# Kotlin Coroutines with SupervisorJob cancel childs

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Why does scope with `SupervisorJob` cancel child launches?
I don't need to know how to fix it, I want to understand the logic. After all, `SupervisorJob` should not cancel child coroutines

```
suspend fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
    scope.launch {
        launch { f1() }
        launch { f2() }
        launch { error() }
    }
}   

suspend fun f1() {
    delay(300)
    println("f1")
}

suspend fun f2() {
    delay(300)
    println("f2")
}
```

Result: Nothing. And why is the error not thrown out?

UPD. If write it so it will be ok. But why?

```
scope.launch { .. }
scope.launch { .. }
scope.launch { .. }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly identified the difference:

```
scope.launch { // there is a new CoroutineScope created here!
    launch { f1() }
    launch { f2() }
    launch { error() }
}
```

The outer `launch` creates a *subscope* of your supervisor scope, and *that* scope does not have a `SupervisorJob`; it is a normal `CoroutineScope` and processes exceptions with cancellations.

Launching directly in the scope with the `SupervisorJob` has the expected behavior, of course.

Comment: that is, all errors necessarily reach scope and are checked there?

Comment: All errors will work their way out to the nearest scope and be handled there or propagated to the next-higher scope.

Comment: If you want it to behave like this, you should write `launch { supervisorScope { launch { ... } launch { ... } } }`.